# Change background color of a view without removing drawable

Tags: android

I have a view with a drawable set on it:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable" />
```

`my_drawable` changes the way the `View` looks when it is clicked/pressed, but does not set its background color. I want to set its background color in the code:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
```

But this removes `my_drawable` from it. How can I change the background color without removing `my_drawable`?

**EDIT**

This is `my_drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@xml/button_round_corner_pressed_shape" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@xml/button_round_corner_default_shape"></item>
</selector>
```

This is `button_round_corner_pressed_shape`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

  <stroke android:width="@dimen/button_pressed_stroke_width"
      android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

  <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_corner_radius" />

</shape>
```

Comment: yourlayout.setSupportButtonTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Activity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
 try with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked for me:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view_background"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
    android:src="@xml/button_round_corner_default_shape" />

<View
    android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
    android:background="@xml/my_drawable" />
```

And in the code:

```
viewBackground = findViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.view_background);
viewBackground.setColorFilter(color);
```

I combined pieces of everyone's answer to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ImageView with the drawable as android:src and change the background as you wish.

Comment: That would work but I need to set the corner radius of the `ImageView` in the xml, not the `background` drawable...do you know how?

Comment: You can create a drawable xml with the item <bitmap /> that holds your image

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to overlap the view with an ImageView so that you can set the background colour in the view and set the drawable in the ImageView.

Comment: That would work but I need to set the corner radius of the `ImageView` in the xml, not the `background` drawable...do you know how?

Comment: For the image view you can create an xml file with corner radius and add it to its background and in the src use your drawable.

Comment: But then my "pressed" state of the selector won't work. I updated my question and included the contents of `my_drawable`

Answer (score 1):

You can use ImageView and set your drawable as below code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green_circle" />
```

Then you can change color of your drawable at run time without changing your drawable:

```
ImageView view=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.view);
view.setColorFilter(Color.RED);
```

Comment: But then my "pressed" state of the selector won't work. I updated my question and included the contents of `my_drawable`

Answer (score 0):

Use CheckedText view with selector for checked , unchecked stated . 
 Onclick just toggle the checked state .

```
checkedTxt.setChecked(true).
```

Answer (score 0):

> But this removes `my_drawable` from it. How can I change the background color without removing `my_drawable`?

You want to change the background color by not removing the my_drawable? That seems confusing my friend. Why would you change the background color if you don't want to remove the drawable?

Which background color do you really want to be changed?

You can also just change the drawable to a new one..

The property `android:background` actually accepts a few types. You can try a drawable and a color.

You can also programmatically change this by using `view.setBackgroundColor(color)` for color, and `view.setBackground(drawable)` for background drawable.

References

- [View setBackgroundColor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int))
- [View setBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Comment: If I set both `setBackgroundColor` and `setBackground`, then the "pressed" state of `my_drawable` won't work. I updated my post to include the contents of `my_drawable`

Comment: Don't do both. If you need to add a drawable pressed state, you need to have a View.OnTouchListener. Under the DOWN MotionEvent you can change the pressed state drawable there and just return to the original drawable on UP MotionEvent.

Comment: Gene, the selected answer is a lot cleaner, don't you think?

Comment: If that's your goal then that is way better. My solution assumes you'd want the pressed state use a drawable.